# How do i use a custom conda environment on a jupyter notebook running on aws sagemaker?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

Completely new to aws. I'm trying to run a .ipynb file on a sagemaker notebook instance in Jupyter Lab. How do I install requirements?

I would like to create and activate a conda environment like this, but it's not working:

```
    conda env create -f environment.yaml
    conda activate ldm
```

What's the best and easiest way to have all dependencies installed?

Comment: Can you post the error log it outputs?

Comment: There are different ways to install dependencies on SageMaker notebook instances. An easy way would be to use `pip`. For example, within a notebook cell you can run `!pip install library-name`.

Comment: If you're seeing this - `CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.`, type `bash` in your command prompt and then run `conda activate ldm` once you're in the base environment.